# Did Jordan Belfort really own the most expensive real estate in the world?

Tags: realism, the-wolf-of-wall-street

In *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), Jordan Belfort narrates these lines about the house that he and his wife Naomi bought:

> Jordan: Seven acres on the Gold Coast of Long Island. **The most expensive real estate
> in the world**. With maids, cooks, landscapers, you name it.

Did Jordan Belfort really own the most expensive real estate in the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Belfort's house was on the Gold Coast of Long Island, NY, USA.

Look online for lists of the most expensive house or real estate in the USA or in the world.

If you look at different lists from different times you will that sometimes they list properties which were not in the Gold Coast of Long Island, or even not in New  York State - or even not in the USA in the case of lists of the most expensive real estate in the world.

I have often noticed that the Gold Coast of Long Island, New York State, USA did not - repeat *not* - have the most expensive house in the USA, let alone the whole world.

I don't think that Belfort was claiming that the most expensive house in the world was the one he bought. Or even a nearby house elsewhere in the Gold Cost. I think that Belfort was bragging that he bought a house in the Gold Coast, a small region (but still tens of square miles I guess) where houses were (or so he claimed) the most expensive in the world per square foot and estates were the most expensive in the world per acre.

Answer (score 0):

This is a misunderstanding on your part I think, the emphasis is meant to be on the **location**.

He's not referring to his specific property but rather the area *"the Gold Coast of Long Island"*